# MySQL SWITCH CASE multiple sort by

Tags: mysql, sorting

I would like to create a query that sorts the result at the hand of two dates.
This at the hand of a switch statement. But that does not seem to work.

Below the simplified version (no fields specified)

```
SELECT *
FROM `system_booking` 
JOIN `system_address`       ON `system_address`.`address_id` = `system_booking`.`booking_address`
JOIN `system_bookingprice`  ON `system_booking`.`booking_id` = `system_bookingprice`.`bookingprice_link`
JOIN `system_vehicle`       ON `system_vehicle`.`vehicle_id` = `system_booking`.`booking_vehicle`
JOIN `system_parkingfee`    ON `system_booking`.`booking_id` = `system_parkingfee`.`parkingfee_link`
WHERE  (`booking_start` LIKE ? OR `booking_end` LIKE ?) 
ORDER BY (
   CASE WHEN `booking_start`  LIKE ?  THEN `booking_start`    ASC
   CASE WHEN `booking_end`    LIKE ?  THEN `booking_end`      ASC
END)
```

This however produces a MySQL error.

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC CASE WHEN `booking_end` LIKE '2015-06-01%' THEN `booking_end` A' at line 9**

I hope that anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The `ASC` of course has no place inside the `CASE` statement … it needs to come _after_ that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `END` for each `CASE` (and a comma too):

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `booking_start`  LIKE ?  THEN `booking_start` END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN `booking_end`    LIKE ?  THEN `booking_end` END) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff

That worked!!!

```
SELECT *
FROM `system_booking` 
JOIN `system_address`       ON `system_address`.`address_id` = `system_booking`.`booking_address`
JOIN `system_bookingprice`  ON `system_booking`.`booking_id` = `system_bookingprice`.`bookingprice_link`
JOIN `system_vehicle`       ON `system_vehicle`.`vehicle_id` = `system_booking`.`booking_vehicle`
JOIN `system_parkingfee`    ON `system_booking`.`booking_id` = `system_parkingfee`.`parkingfee_link`
WHERE  (`booking_start` LIKE ? OR `booking_end` LIKE ?) 
ORDER BY 
   (CASE WHEN `booking_start`  LIKE ?  THEN `booking_start`    END) ASC,
   (CASE WHEN `booking_end`    LIKE ?  THEN `booking_end`       END) ASC
```

Thanks!!